# AEM Human Translation Getting The Response From Server?

Tags: java, adobe, aem, sling

I use bootstrap translation framework (Git : https://forums.adobe.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAdobe-Marketing-Cloud%2Faem-translation-framework-bootstrap-connector%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fbundle%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fadobe%2Fgranite%2Ftranslation%2Fconnector%2Fbootstrap%2Fcore%2Fimpl%2FBootstrapTranslationServiceImpl.java) : I use this method uploadTranslationObject for posting to my server and one request is completed.

I just have a small doubt like i use human translation the response will be coming after some X delay time.Now i am wondering how do i get the response once the translated response is ready from my server??

I have the logic of returning the translated xml on my server but question is how do i return it?? I mean where should my server post on some api or will ame keeps constantly looking for the response?

Can someone please let me know with a small code or a existing method? I need to find in which method of the code will the response from server will be handled ??

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: There is no push API in AEM that can be called by an external application to know when the translation is ready. You can always write a custom servlet to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to monitor the status of the Documents(`TranslationObjects`). When you upload the TO for translation via `uploadTranslationObject()` change the status of the TO to 'SUBMITTED' or 'TRANSLATION_IN_PROGRESS'.
Then in the `getTranslationObjectStatus()` you will make request to your server to know if the TO are translated or not. If the TO is translated then you can change the status of the TO to 'TRANSLATED'. The method `getTranslationObjectStatus()` will return `TranslationStatus` as TRANSLATED, this will invoke `getTranslatedObject()` where you will download the translated TO and return it as `InputStream`.

**Note:** `getTranslationObjectStatus()` and other status update helper methods will be called when you refresh the *TranslationJob* Page.